# VLAN tagging for single IP's

Tags: networking, iptables, dhcp, vlan

I have a large number of computers whose MAC addresses I do not have in advance.

At a time, I will connect a buch of them to a switch and each should get an IP from a DHCP server.

I like to force a certain IP address for every port of the switch, because I will boot some rescue system and I will log into via ssh.

So whatever computer I connect for e.g. on port 1 of the switch, it should get the same, fixed IP address, and every computer on port 2 should get another IP.

I would like to have all computers in the same subnet and only on DHCP that serves the IP addresses.

I guess this should be possible using VLANs on the switch. But how to I tag the package on the Linux server?

Can the DHCP already tag the packets?

Should I use ebtables or iptables?

Or must I set up a bridge with different interfaces for each VLAN and then how does the DHCP handle this?

Comment: Your case is very similar to this [question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16062/assign-an-ip-address-based-on-switch-port)

Comment: Yes, the questions is similar. But I do not have a Cisco switch. I need a solution with a DHCP running on Linux.

Comment: I guess that if you don't have DHCP in the switch, then it can't be possible.

Comment: It seems that DHCP option82 can do the trick. I have to check if I can enable this in the switch.

Comment: I can use and define VLAN's on the switch but not set DHCP option82. So I have to do something on the Linux server running DHCP.

Comment: What is your switch make and model? And what is your router make and model? There is a way to do this, it is alot of config for a pretty simple task though.

Answer (score 0):

VLAN tagging generally happens at a lower OSI network level than DHCP/IP protocols; I don't believe any of your current solutions will work, because the computers you're connecting will have to have set a VLAN that matches the port they're plugged in to, which is enough configuration that they may as well use manually configured IP addresses.

It sounds like you want some kind of router-side configuration that decides which IP address to give based on which port is being used; this won't be covered by any kind of stock DHCP server, you'll need to find some specific way of communicating with the router firmware to identify which port it was plugged in to.

Comment: I tought I can configure some VLAN on each port of the switch. Then I only need to add the VLAN tag to the IP packets the DHCP server is sending out. And tagging all traffic to this IP address, which will then be send automatically to one specific port of the switch. Is this possible?

Comment: I cannot use manual configured IP addresses, since I will use a PXE boot environment and a read-only nfsroot.

Comment: You'd need a DHCP server using the vlan id as criteria for incoming packets. For example, isc-dhcp-server actively *removes* vlan tagged packets from its input to avoid duplicate packets (tagged from parent interface + untagged from vlan interface) ( isc-dhcp-4.3.5/common/lpf.c ). You'd have to do the opposite: bind only to a normal non-vlan interface and not remove the tagged packet. You'd have to enhance the configuration syntax, probably enhance the lease database format (eg: being able to differenciate the same MAC from two different VLANs) etc. Seems a lot of patch to do.